# How to check if a dynamic collection of objects have the same keys recursively?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am given an object which has dynamic properties, but all of its properties values are objects too (keys at this level can differ which is fine). But for each of these objects, I want to make sure all of them have the same keys and recursively too. For example

Given A where

```
A = {
    'en' : {
        's1' : '',
        's2' : {
            's3' : '',
            's4' : ''
        }
    },
    'fr' : {
        's1' : '',
        's2' : {
            's3' : '',
            's4' : ''
        }
    }
}
```

these two are the same, because they have the same key values recursively.

```
A = {
    'en' : {
        's1' : '',
        's2' : {
            's3' : '',
            's4' : ''
        }
    },
    'fr' : {
        's1' : '',
        's2' : {
            's3' : '',
            's5' : ''
        }
    }
}
```

this would be false because s5 is different and don't exist in at least one other.

Essentially the purpose is to create an object which has language objects inside and I can put any language objects I want, so its dynamic. But for each language object, all it's keys should be synchronized and the same with all other language object.

I have this

```
this.compareKeys = function(dataObj) {
    var checkObj = {};
    for(var prop in dataObj) {
        if (dataObj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            var obj = dataObj[prop];
            var keysStr = JSON.stringify(Object.keys(obj).sort());
            var keys = Object.keys(checkObj);
            if (keys.length == 0) {
                checkObj[keysStr] = true;
            } else if (!checkObj.hasOwnProperty(keysStr)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

but how do I make it work for recursively? This only checks 1 level deep.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, i edited my examples a bit, had a little typo in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can *compare* the lang object with a **structure** object:

```
var struct = {
    's1' : '',
    's2' : {
        's3' : '',
        's4' : ''
    }
}

var lang = {
    'en' : {
        's1' : '',
        's2' : {
            's3' : '',
            's4' : ''
        }
    },
    'fr' : {
        's1' : '',
        's2' : {
            's3' : '',
            's4' : ''
        }
    }
}
```

Therefore get all keys in the lang object **recursively**:

```
function getAllKeys(obj, res) { // Get all keys in string format
    for(k in obj) {
        res.push(k);
        if(typeof(obj[k]) === "object") {
            var o = obj[k];
            getAllKeys(o, res);
        } 
    }

    return res.join("");
}
```

You give this function an object and a result array as arguements:

```
function f(obj, []) { ... }
```

Check if the value is an object:

```
if(typeof(obj[k]) === "object") { ... }
```

If so run the function again with `obj[k]` as the new object and so on.

For comparison reasons the function outputs a string!

The next step is to **compare** lang object with structure object:

```
function compareObjWithStructure(obj, struct) {
    var s = getAllKeys(struct, []);
    for(k in obj) {
        var ks = getAllKeys(obj[k], []);
        if(ks !== s) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ob9xq1ea/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can compare two objects level by level with passing keys array.

```
if (obj1.constructor === Array && obj2.constructor === Array) {
  flag = obj1.length === obj2.length;
  if (flag) {
    obj1.forEach(function(key) {
      map[key] = (map[key] || 0) + 1;
    });
    obj2.forEach(function(key) {
      flag = flag && (map[key] !== undefined);
    });
  }

  return flag;
}
```

If this level keys are the same, then check their children.

```
Object.keys(obj1).forEach(function(key) {
  if (typeof obj1[key] === 'object') {
    flag = flag && compareKeys(obj1[key], obj2[key]);
  }
});
```

Here is the [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/1z1nuyr0/2/)

Hope this is useful.